# add optional query parameters into R POST request

Tags: r, post, httr

I want to make a POST request to https://rest.ensembl.org. Currently the following works:

```
server <- "https://rest.ensembl.org"
ext <- "/vep/human/hgvs"
r <- POST(paste(server, ext, sep = ""), 
          content_type("application/json"), 
          accept("application/json"), 
          body = '{ "hgvs_notations" : ["chr2:g.10216G>T"] }')
```

which results in this URL `https://rest.ensembl.org/vep/human/hgvs/chr2:g.10216G>T`. I would like to use the `?` parameter to modify my URL to `https://rest.ensembl.org/vep/human/hgvs/chr2:g.10216G>T?CADD=1` however I can't see how to do this in the POST request function in R.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

If it is always the same parameter you need to send, why not just include it in the URI then?
You could do something like `POST( paste0(server, ext, '?CADD=1'), [...] )`.
Or would that not be dynamic enough for your usecase?

The following would be the less hacky way to include parameters:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

r <- POST(
  paste0(server, ext),
  query = list('CADD' = 1),
  content_type_json(),
  accept_json(),
  body = toJSON(list('hgvs_notations' = c('chr2:g.10216G>T')))
)
```

Comment: I couldn't get your code to work. I can get it to run if I include the `query = list('CADD' = 1)` in my original post, but it doesn't make a difference i.e. no additional info from not including the query parameter. What output did you get when you tried it?

Comment: I don't know what your server and ext parameters are... Couldnt try it.

Comment: sorry my bad! - have added them in.

Comment: So, for some reason, when you convert the body to a json string before sending this, it works. I've added my response, using `jsonlite::toJSON()` on the list.